# Setting Up QtCreator to develop apps for arm7 devices on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

How do I setup QtCreator to compile "Qt for Embedded Linux" applications for arm7. I am quite new to cross-compiling and tool-chains. I am working on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to download the [Qt libraries 4.8.6 for embedded Linux](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.6/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6.tar.gz) from `qt-project.org/downloads` and configure `Qt Creator` to use the `QMake` version that comes with the install from `Tools->Options->Build&Run->Qt Versions`. Also make sure that the compiler you use is configured properly on the `Compilers` tab and that you also have the kits configured on the `Kits` tab and you should be ready to go.

I hope this helps...